# find rank of row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some records that I want to check rank of rows and if the rank is  greater than 100 I will set permission.
I wrote flowing code to find rank of records but when I used the rank or row_number function without an additional field (like username or family) it doesn't work though it does works with one of the additional fields.

```
SELECT * from
(Select username,
Rank() over(order by point desc) as  'ranking' 
from student) t
 where (username='test')
```

I want to find a record and set a variable with rank of this record.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question?

Comment: Why is the tag `MySQL` there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your sqlser version supprts cte. If it is a >= 2005 sqlserver [this is your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82419):

```
create table #student ( username varchar(10), point int );

insert into #student values
( 'a', 10 ),
( 'b', 20 ),
( 'test', 15 );

declare @var int;

with cte as (
  select username,
  Rank() over(order by point desc) as  [ranking] 
  from #student
)
select  @var = [ranking]  from cte where username = 'test';
print str( @var );
```

Results:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this query ?

```
Select count(*)+1 as rank from student 
where point > (select point from student where username = 'test')
```

Wich should return the number of user with less points than the selected user

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with the question asked.

Comment: This query gives a rank ... thanks for the -1 ... where is your suggest ?

Comment: Your welcome. The query doesn't rank the students, it just counts the number of students that have less points then the user names 'test' (+1).  Definitely not what the poster asked for.

Comment: If you're third, your rank is the number of persons who have more points than you + 1.

Comment: Now I understand. You missed the tag, this is a SQL-Server question, not MySQL.  
If that's what the original author had wanted, it could be solved easily with a RANK function like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23291/3
BTW, that's exactly what he posted in the question!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17981/discussion-between-gidil-and-loic-bcn)

Answer (score 0):

For `RANK` to work, you need to specify `PARTITION BY` column over which you want to Rank over, and then, `ORDER BY` is like if there comes a situation like both the Rank columns have the same value and there is a conflict, then order by column will sort out the issue by ordering those conflicting records..

Comment: Simply incorrect. [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) clearly shows that you don't specify the column before the ORDER BY. That's what the ORDER BY is for!

Comment: @Gidil: that documentation says `partition_by_clause divides the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to which the function is applied. If not specified, the function treats all rows of the query result set as a single group. `

Comment: This has little to do with what you posted (since PARTITION BY is optional).   
Moreover, it's painfully obvious you don't have much experience in this area. The PARTITION BY element allows several ranks within the same result set, separated according to the partition.